# Move(slide) 3 different images from left to right using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 images (cars) that I want to move across the screen. When I click on the "Start" button, the relevant car should move across the screen. Car1, Car2 and Car3. Each button needs to activate three different timer events. Each car should move using the "margin-left" style property while increasing the distance parameter by the amount of pixels traveled.

I also want a winner. Whichever car crosses or overlaps the checked image should display an alertbox indicating the winner and stopping all the timers.

This is what I have thus far:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Welcome to div races!</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 134px;
        height: 51px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">Div Races!</div>

<div id="track">

<div class="lane"><div id="Car1">
  <img id="Car1" alt="Car1" class="style1" longdesc="Car1" 
      src="Car1.jpg" /></div></div><!--Car1-->
<button onclick="Car1()">Start</button>

<div class="lane"><div id="Car2">
  <img id="Car2" alt="Car2" class="style1" longdesc="Car2" 
      src="Car2.jpg" /></div></div><!--Car2-->
<button onclick="Car2()">Start</button>

<div class="lane"><div id="Car3">
  <img id="Car3" alt="Car3" class="style1" longdesc="Car3" 
      src="Car3.jpg" /></div></div><!--Crankshaft-->
<button onclick="Car3()">Start</button>

</div><!--track-->

<div id="footer">Click on a start button to start a racecar!</div>

</body>
</html>




function Car1() {
var animate, left = 0, imgObj = null;
init();
    function init(){

       imgObj = document.getElementById('rusty');
       imgObj.style.position= 'absolute';
       imgObj.style.top = '240px';
       imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
       imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';

       moveRight();
    }

    function moveRight(){
        left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left, 10);

        if (10 >= left) {
            imgObj.style.left = (left + 5) + 'px';
            imgObj.style.visibility='visible';

            animate = setTimeout(function(){moveRight();},20); 

            //stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,20);
        } else {
            stop();
        }
        //f();
    }

    function stop(){
       clearTimeout(animate);
    }

window.onload = function() {init();};
}

function Car2() {
var animate, left = 0, imgObj = null;
init();
    function init(){

       imgObj = document.getElementById('dusty');
       imgObj.style.position= 'absolute';
       imgObj.style.top = '240px';
       imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
       imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';

       moveRight();
    }

    function moveRight(){
        left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left, 10);

        if (10 >= left) {
            imgObj.style.left = (left + 5) + 'px';
            imgObj.style.visibility='visible';

            animate = setTimeout(function(){moveRight();},20); 

            //stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,20);
        } else {
            stop();
        }
        //f();
    }

    function stop(){
       clearTimeout(animate);
    }

window.onload = function() {init();};
}

function Car3() {
var animate, left = 0, imgObj = null;
init();
    function init(){

       imgObj = document.getElementById('crankshaft');
       imgObj.style.position= 'absolute';
       imgObj.style.top = '240px';
       imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
       imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';

       moveRight();
    }

    function moveRight(){
        left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left, 10);

        if (10 >= left) {
            imgObj.style.left = (left + 5) + 'px';
            imgObj.style.visibility='visible';

            animate = setTimeout(function(){moveRight();},20); 

            //stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,20);
        } else {
            stop();
        }
        //f();
    }

    function stop(){
       clearTimeout(animate);
    }

window.onload = function() {init();};
}
```

Am I on the right track? 
The code I used was found on the website.
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you up for using jquery?

Comment: Unfortunately I am only allowed to use JavaScript.